# LINQ Добавить строку в каждые 5 позиций списка

Tags: c#, linq

Помогите переписать код с помощью Linq

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LastName { get; set; }
}

var UserList = new List<User>();
var NewUserList = new List<User>();
int i = 0;
foreach(var user in UserList)
{
    if (i++ % 5 == 0)
    {
        NewUserList.Add(new User() { Id = 0,Name = "Иванов" });
    }
    NewUserList.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: Дай человеку в руки молоток, так для него все станет гвоздями. Зачем тут `LINQ`? Это средство запросов и некоторых преобразований, а не волшебная палочка. Ну хорошо, если вы так хотите функционального стиля - накатаю вам ответ. Ожидайте.

Comment: Просто пройдись `for (var i=0; i<UserList.Count; i+=5)`

Comment: Не сделать тебе это линком. Вот если бы ты вставлял Ивана на позицию кратную 5 вместо того что там есть то да, а ты вставляешь между, смещая то, что есть на позицию дальше...

Answer (score 5):

Ну например так:

```
var NewUserList = UserList.SelectMany(
    (u, idx) => idx % 5 == 0 ? new[] { new User() { Id = 0, Name = "Иванов" }, u } :
                               new[] { u }).ToList();
```

Ну или можно, например, подключить из nuget [`MoreLinq`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) и написать более изящно:

```
var NewUserList =
    UserList.Batch(5)
            .SelectMany(part => part.Prepend(new User() { Id = 0, Name = "Иванов" }))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: А вот про `SelectMany` - я и не вспомнил.. хех. Но все равно попахивает.

Comment: @Сергей: Ну вот вам совсем хороший вариант.

Comment: Лучше, но требует внешнюю зависимость. Увы.

Comment: Интересно, а по производительности как? По любому оверхед есть.

Comment: @Сергей: Мир несовершенен. А методы типа `Batch` недолго и самому написать, если хочется, минута работы.

Comment: @Сергей: Ну если мы выжимаем производительность, то нужно как минимум вместо `ToList` использовать `new List<User>(UserList.Count * 6 / 5)`. А так вообще, раз автор простит LINQ, то ему, вероятно, производительность не настолько критична.

Comment: ну если нет ограничений по памяти - и совсем уж не извращаться, то LINQ порой быстрее самописных велосипедов. Был у меня случай - когда линком быстрее было на больших выборках, чем циклом пройтись - в последнем случае выигрыш был только на небольших коллекциях.

Comment: @Сергей: LINQ ленивый, в этом плюс, особенно если не материализовать раньше времени. Может быть, это сыграло.

Comment: ну наверняка какие-то оптимизации.

Comment: О, поправил свой ответ - добавил туда ленивости. Феншуй)

Comment: @Сергей: Да, так выглядит лучше. Но я бы делал не материализицию массива, а обход `IEnumerable` через `foreach`. А индекс бы тащил отдельно.

Comment: Да, пожалуй в таком случае foreach будет лучше.

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю зачем вам это надо - выглядит сомнительно, ну да ладно. Отвечаю:

Не сделать в LINQ'е такого, по крайней мере так чтоб не сломать там нафиг мозг - и потом никто в этом без бутылки не разберется, так что сделаем немного иначе. (P.S. Ну как я и говорил - сделать можно как в ответе VladD - но читается это весьма худо, либо требует внешних зависимостей, что зачастую бывает излишним).

Вынесем лучше в метод-расширение с глаз долой (особенно если это будет вызываться больше одного раза) заодно сделаем функцию **"ленивой"**, чтоб вообще по феншую:

```
public static class UserExtension
{
   public static IEnumerable<User> InsertIvan5(this IEnumerable<User> list)
   {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var user in list)
        {
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                yield return new User() { Id = 0, Name = "Иванов" };
            }

            yield return user;
            i++; // Так читабельнее нежели инкремировать ее внутри условия. 
                 // К черту эту сишную магию.
        }
    }
}
```

В таком случае в коде будет вызываться так:

```
var NewUserList = UserList.InsertIvan5();
```

Опять же имя функции лучше как-нибудь более вразумительное дать - ну тут уж вы сами. Технически - очень похоже на `LINQ` так же можно заключать в цепочки со стандартными `LINQ` функциями и даже можно цепочку из этих самых функций нагородить. В LINQ тоже многое на методах-расширениях держится, а внутри зачастую никакой магии - все те же циклы и коллекции.

Comment: Ну вот, пока я писал, что вы работаете с IEnumerable как с а) конечной и б) неизменной последовательностью -- уже исправлено. )) Теперь плюс, однозначно. (Ещё правда я не уверен, что нужно первым же элементом сразу вставлять Иванова, но это уже мелочи)

Comment: Так было у автора вопроса. Так что с меня взятки гладки)

Answer (score -1):

```
var userList = new List<User>();
// ... заполняем юзеров
int i = 0;
var newUserList = new List<User>();
userList.ForEach(x => 
{
    if((i++ % 5)==0) {
         newUserList.Add(new User() { Id = 0,Name = "Иванов" });    
    }
    newUserList.Add(x); 
});
```

Comment: Может быть объясните за что минусуем?

Comment: А вы запускать то пробовали?

Comment: @Сергей да, тут проверял https://ideone.com/PGad7W

Comment: Оно делает не то, что надо, Дмитрий. Внимательно прочти код в вопросе.

Comment: Я уж молчу - что вносить побочки в виде переменной `i` внутрь лямд - это ну поистину странное решение. Напрашивается вопрос нафига здесь вообще LINQ если нужно так извращаться.

Comment: @Сергей я и не говорил что это красиво, хотя так иногда делают, но зато соответсвует условию, и да, там другой код, сейчас подумаю как исправить и можно ли.

Comment: Попробуй - я не вижу тут более менее удобоваримого способа. А городить огород в такой простой задаче аля LINQ ради LINQ'а - считаю плохой идеей.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: У `Where` есть перегрузка с индексом, лучше использовать её.

Comment: @VladD, Все равно не соорудить коллекции со сдвигом.

Comment: Обновил код, теперь работает в соответствии с вопросом. Хотя получается почти что обычный For. )))

Comment: В итоге получилось тоже самое, что было =))))

Comment: Да )) но с использованием Linq подобного выражения ))

Comment: Конгениально, mon cher ami =)